# Transfer string content to a file in remote machine using java

Tags: java, jsch

I need to place a string content in a remote file.

Ideally, I used to create a file in local and then transfer that file to remote machine.

**Below is the code snippet I used, to copy file to remote.**

```
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel; 

        File file = new File(filePathWithName);//To read the file in local machine
        try {
            sftpChannel.cd(location);//Remote location
            //Transferring the file to RemoteLocation.
            sftpChannel.put(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName());//.(Here I don't want read a file.) //Instead I want copy a content which is in string variable, something like below two lines, to the remote location.
            String content = "abcdefg";
            sftpChannel.put(content,"someFileName")
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sftpChannel.exit();
```

Is there any reference or documentation to overcome reading a file in local to create the same in remote machine.

-Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you'd like to be able to copy some string data to a remote machine without reading a file locally. If you look at the [javadoc](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)), `put` accepts `InputStream`. So you do:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
sftpChannel.put(stream, "name.txt");
```

Note that you can also `put(String dst)` where you can write to the `OutputStream` that is returned. But I didn't show that.